# Is using a union to give more access methods like this safe?

Tags: c++, matrix, 3d, unions

I'm making a 4x4 Matrix class, with the data internally represented as an array of 16 floats.  Sometimes I may want to access this array directly, but other times I may just want to access an array slot by name.

```
class Matrix{
    union{
        float array[16];
        struct{
            float a1, a2, a3, a4;
            float b1, b2, b3, b4;
            float c1, c2, c3, c4;
            float d1, d2, d3, d4;
        }named;
        struct{
            float a[4];
            float b[4];
            float c[4];
            float d[4];
        }row;
    }
}

// use
m.array[3] = 1.5f;
m.named.d1 = m.row.a[3];
printf("%f", m.named.d1); // should be 1.5
```

Is this type of thing sane, or will it massively backfire in ways I cannot begin to dream of?
It seems like the later, but I really enjoy having multiple access methods.

This is for manipulating 3D points for graphics stuff.  It's a separate question in itself, but any suggestions for a library that has these things already figured out is entirely welcome.

Comment: Accessing inactive union member is an [undefined behavior in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-undefined) (not C). Though it works on some compilers, it can fail on others. So at least you cannot claim that your code is portable.

Comment: @drop - aw, I was afraid of that.  I guess I can technically use getter methods, but 16+ method definitions is too much trouble.  I guess I'll just have to stick to an array

Comment: If you want to provide a convenience for user, you could also overload `operator[]` or `operator()`, to imitate multidimensional array. That is how most C++ math libraries do it. Some of them also provide different ways of "streaming into and out of" matrix/vector via overloaded `operator<<` and `operator>>` This way you keep you code sane and give user syntactic sugar even better than union aliasing could give